# Flow uitextview (iOS7) within parallelogram shape

Tags: ios7, uitextview

I have a series of uitextviews in a paged scrollview. I would like to have the text within each page flow within a skewed rectangle (parallelogram). Image attached (I want the text to flow within the white outline).

[image: white outline is the flow shape needed]

Code below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.count; i++) {

        CGRect framee;
        framee.origin.x = self.uis_scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        framee.origin.y = 0;
        framee.size = self.uis_scrollView.frame.size;

        UITextView *newTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:framee];

        UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [rectanglePath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(652, 687)];
        [rectanglePath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(680, 687)];
        [rectanglePath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(746, 541)];
        [rectanglePath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(718, 541)];
        [rectanglePath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(652, 687)];
        [rectanglePath closePath];
        UIBezierPath * imgRect = rectanglePath;
        newTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect];

        [newTextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [newTextView setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [newTextView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
        newTextView.text = [imageArray objectAtIndex:i];
        newTextView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [_uis_scrollView addSubview:newTextView];
    }
```

Maybe it is only for flowing around? Maybe I need to 'draw' a slanted rectangle on the right side which will restrict content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of the exclusion path is indeed only to make text flow around it. you should create one or more exclusion path(s) that cover the triangular area where you don't want to see any text. Keep in mind that these paths have to be **in the coordinate system of the `UITextView`**. If I have a textview with size `{320,218}` and I want to cut out a triangular portion to the right, the code would look like this:

```
UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint: CGPointMake(320, 0)];
[path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(320, 218)];
[path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(210, 0)];
[path closePath];
self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[path];
```

and the result looks like this:

[image: screenshot of excluded triangle textview]

Your problem is that you want to subtract a rectangle that is in the **superviews** coordinate system from *each* textView. There is, to my knowledge, no method to create arbitrary `UIBezierPath` intersections with a `CGRect`, so you will have to calculate the coordinates of several `UIBezierPath` triangles manually for each textView.

For simplicity's sake, you could just calculate the intersection points between the hypotenuse of the triangular exclusion path and the textView's rect. Here is a stylised picture of your screen, rotated by 90 degrees to the left:

[image: geometry]